# onDatachange is called and crash the app when i remove value from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

**i am making an app which have function of sending request request to users and i storing senders user id as key and "true"  as value whan user send the request. But when he cancel the request, value removed from the database but on dataChange is called and compare the value with null as in the code **

```
friend_requests = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(phone)
                    .child("Friend_Requests").child(user.getPhoneNumber());
            friend_requests.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("null"))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        follow.setText("Requested");
                    }
                        Log.d("ahmed12", "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .You are checking String="null" which is a value .

```
 @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue()==null)
                {
                   //Logic for cancelled friend request
                }
                else
                {
                    follow.setText("Requested");
                }
                    Log.d("ahmed12", "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.getValue());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change is to reverse the comparison:

```
if("null".equals(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)))
```

This should get rid of the error message, although it's hard to say whether it will do what you want.

The reason for the latter is that it's quite uncommon to compare to a literal `"null"` string. Usually code compares to `null` (instead of `"null"`) to see if something has a value/is initialized.

For example, if you want to check if the snapshot has a value, you'd do that with:

```
if(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) != null)
```

Or even simpler:

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists())
```